# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is it unusual for a flashback to have a very long dialogue?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/is-it-unusual-for-a-flashback-to-have-a-very-long-dialogue)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Improving techniques independently: Description](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/improving-techniques-independently-description)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Dealing with potential copyright issues: manga](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/dealing-with-potential-copyright-issues-manga)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Tenses I should use in a translated-novel](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/tenses-i-should-use-in-a-translated-novel)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Iambic pentameter: how do you use words with 'secondary stressed' syllables?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7722/iambic-pentameter-how-do-you-use-words-with-secondary-stressed-syllables)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is a glossary needed in a novel?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7586/is-a-glossary-needed-in-a-novel)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How to advertise a free e-book?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7681/how-to-advertise-a-free-e-book)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Overuse of bullet points](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/overuse-of-bullet-points)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Background speech with foreground dialogue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7761/background-speech-with-foreground-dialogue)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to avoid specifying the gender in English when the original text does not specify it?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/how-to-avoid-specifying-the-gender-in-english-when-the-original-text-does-not-sp)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)